# How to disable browser case based dropdown lists?

Tags: html, browser

**Situation:** I have an autocomplete textbox. If the user start to type the options appear in a dropdown menu and the user can select the correct one.

**The problem:** If the user enter letters manualy the browser ll store them in his case and try to "help" the user by an other dropwon menu too. So both menu appears on top of each other what is very annoying. Like this: [image: Like this.]

Thank you very much for any tips how to get rid of the browser's one! (The users may use chrome/explorer/firefox)

Comment: Add `autocomplete="off"` to the input tag.

Comment: Ohh this was much easier than I tought :) Thank you very much!

https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/prop_form_autocomplete.asp

Comment: Glad to help. :)